# Baking normal maps high to low resolution object

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I have high resolution objects which I want to bake to low resolution objects to save size and loading time, I know the steps of baking high res to low res (which generates a new normal map applied on the low res object).

But I also have a normal map applied to the high res object (example: tiles with grooves), which I also need to apply to the low res object, so in this case I have 2 normal maps must be applied to the low res object.

Is there a quick way to do that? I've read something about adding node that merges 2 normal map nodes, is this the only way? because I have a lot of objects and I need a quick way to do that.

Comment: If you bake a high-poly that has a normal map itself, the (fake) 3D relief created by this normal map will also be baked

Comment: @moonboots You mean will be baked to one single image? and what if I wanted to change the texture to another texture that has another normal map? I need to bake the whole thing again? including high res to low res?

Comment: another solution, as you said, is to bake the high-poly without its normal map plugged, then use this normal map on the low-poly, as you can mix 2 normal maps

Comment: In the last solution, is there anyway to automate the baking process and make it faster? because I have many objects, some baking plugins can make baking faster but in this specific case where I have 2 normal maps I think it will be difficult?

Comment: i don't know these plugins you are talking about, maybe someone will know